# Ember.js how to concat two objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an object in Ember (let's call it `existing`):

```
 var existing = {
     items: [
        ...
     ],
     ...
 }
```

On the callback of hitting a server side request, there is a new response called `result` which looks the same as `existing`. I need to take the `items` in existing, and prepend them to the new `result`. So I have the following:

```
  var result = { ... };
  var existing = this.get('content');
  result.items = result.items.concat(existing.items);
  this.set('content', result);
```

The problem is, when rendered in the template, it is just displaying the new items from `result`, the old items from `existing` are not being displayed even though are in `items`. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume it's because ember already has the bindings on the parent array object and when you call concat, you are actually returning a new array object in JavaScript - and it doesn't have any of Embers bindings associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that using `concat` which is not supported in `Ember.Array` (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) does not trigger bindings and therefore your view is not updated. To get the items arrays merged you could do something like:

```
var result = { ... };
var existing = this.get('content');
result.items.forEach(item) {
  existing.items.pushObject(item);
}
this.set('content', existing);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If result.items is an array and you want to use the javascript concat method you can call toArray on the existing.items enumerable.

```
var result = { ... };
var existing = this.get('content');
result.items = result.items.concat(existing.get('items').toArray());
this.set('content', result);
```

If result.items is already an Ember.Enumerable I would use pushObjects or addObjects. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_addObjects

```
var result = { ... };
var existing = this.get('content.items');
result.items = result.get('items').addObjects(existing);
this.set('content', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post, but since there isn't an accepted answer, I thought I'd throw in what I feel is the best option. I recently found myself needing to concat a bunch of `DS.ManyArray` together and this was the solution I came up w/:

```
var myArrayOfHasManyArrays = ...;
var concatenated = [].concat.apply([], myArrayOfHasManyArrays.invoke('toArray'));
```

Hope this helps!